# How to generate shareable APK from my react native project

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I generated signed apk - but the result non installable apk

Apk not installed and these are the initial warnings

[image]

[image]

generating debug (not signed apk) is not working with the client

> Could not connect to development server (500)

I just can't share the apk with my client - that's too bad

Comment: which version of react-native are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`Google Play Protect` is a feature that `protects` your device by scanning apps that are downloaded from the store or installed with `APK`. I think it's good to set it up because it protects your smartphone, but sometimes you have to turn it off because it doesn't work when you install the `APK` as needed or because of this feature.

ex) Apps not installed during app installation.

1. Launch the `Google Play Store` and click on the left menu bar to
   select `Play Protect`.
2. You can see that `Play Protect` is working here. To turn off
   features, search the lower device for security threats and select
   the feature supplement to detect harmful apps to **turn off**.
3. Click OK when the warning window appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error like development server error, you need to generate release build apk of your project. There is a documation about how you should generate your apk in link below.

[Documation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)